# Suppress Page Footer After Subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to suppress all the page footers on the main report on all pages that have a subreport and I'm having some trouble.

The subreport is in the report footer and starts on a new page. The subreport could be 1 or 10 pages so doing it by page number is out.

I've tried setting a global variable in the main report header and setting it to false and then changing the variable just before the subreport section (I change the variable in report footer a, and then the subreport is in report footer b)  to true and then tried to suppress the page footer based on that global variable but to no avail.

I feel like I'm really close but just missing something. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Try this it will work

```
1) Create this formula and place it on the Group Header 2 Section:

whileprintingrecords;
numbervar x := x + 1;
"";

2) Create this formula and place it on the Page Header Section:

whileprintingrecords;
numbervar x := 0;
"";

3) Go to the Section Expert > Select the Page Footer Section > Click the formula button     beside 'Suppress' and use this code:

numbervar x = 0;

Let me know how this goes.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but are probably just missing a detail or two.

In the report footer, create a global boolean variable and then suppress the page footer based on this variable. BUT, you need to use the `whileprintingrecords` keyword for both formulas. Ex:

```
//Declare variable in report footer
whileprintingrecords;
booleanvar suppressFooter := true

//Suppress page footer
whileprintingrecords;
booleanvar suppressFooter
```

Comment: I feel like this should work, but now it suppresses EVERY page footer, instead of just the ones that the subreport is on.

Comment: These must be the _only_ two references to that variable. Don't bother declaring/initializing it anywhere but in the report footer.

Comment: So I have a function in my report footer that looks like this `WhilePrintingRecords;
BooleanVar suppressPageFooter = true;`

and then my suppress function looks like this: 
`WhilePrintingRecords;
BooleanVar suppressPageFooter;
suppressPageFooter`

and I've also tried:

`WhilePrintingRecords;
BooleanVar suppressPageFooter;`

Right now none of the footers are being suppressed. What am I missing?

Comment: Your initialization is wrong. You are using the comparison operator instead of the assignment operator. You want `:=`.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. However, now that I've fixed that all of the page footers are suppressed just like before